# Incorrect syntax near '' SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i'm a beginner with sqlserver, and i'm trying to compile a function on db, but a got some issues

[Error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7T6J.png)

i'm guessing that is missing parentheses in importants components.

```
SELECT
  somefields
FROM
  table S,
  table2 SF
WHERE
      mycondition = myothercondition
  AND mycondition = myothercondition
  AND S.mycondition = myothercondition 
  AND SF.mycondition  = myothercondition 
  -- BELOW IS MY PROBLEM
  AND 
        (
          (NOT EXISTS
            (
                SELECT
                  1 
                FROM
                  table3 s 
                WHERE
                  mycondition = 'S'
            )
            AND
            (
                SELECT
                  CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(mm, myfield, myfield),103), 103) <= CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, myfield, 103), 103) -- INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR '<'
                FROM
                  mytable A 
                WHERE
                  mycondition = '607'
            )
          ) 
            OR 
            (
                SELECT
                  1
            )
        ) -- Incorrect syntax near ')'
        AND CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(mm, MYFIELD, MYFIELD), 103), 103) <= CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, MYFIELD, 103), 103) 
        AND mycondition = 
        (
           SELECT
              MAX(MYFIELD) 
           FROM
              MYFIELD WITH(NOLOCK) 
           WHERE
              Mycondition = mycondition
              AND mycondition = mycondition
              AND mycondition = '086'
        )
        AND (NOT EXISTS -- Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'
        (
           SELECT
              1 
           FROM
              table SF3 WITH(NOLOCK) 
           WHERE
              SF3.myfield= SF.myfield
              AND SF3.myfield= SF.myfield
              AND SF3.myfield IN
              (
                 '086',
                 '086'
              )
              AND SF3.myfield= 'S'
        )
```

I imagine that is happening some problems with the '(', but i really don't know, what's the problem.
sorry but i need hide the field names and tables.

Comment: Welcome Daniel. I think there are many pbs here

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: in your where you need to do some test exple x = true, x= y, some logical operations. Some part of your code in the where you dont have logical operations but pure selects:

Comment: Did you really write this big query without executing it even once during the time? I used to execute for each step added.

Comment: break this big beast down, you've got a bunch of derived tables. Find the smallest query possible that throws your error.

Comment: And is there a reason you seem to be double-converting?

Comment: As zip said, your first error is just a select with a `<=` in it, that's the first issue. And as Andrew stated, you need to break it down into smaller components to debug it.

Comment: This query is overcomplicated. Whatever it tries to do, there are easier ways to do it. `NOLOCK` won't fix bad queries, it can actually make things worse because it reads dirty data and can actually return *duplicate* rows

Comment: `TABLE` is a reserved keyowrd word, so you'll need to quote it. In your subquery, on line 26, you have a boolean expression for a column expression; that doesn't make sense. Your `NOT EXISTS` (which starts on line 14) has an `AND` inside it, which doesn't make sense either. Then I'm sure there's more problems.

Comment: My advice is to read up on joins. The syntax you are using is very, very old. The way you have approached the problem seems a little odd. Also, you are using `NOLOCK`, ensure you know what that means before using it, or it will cause you headaches.

Comment: hmm, tks guys, i will try breaks in small components and try compile to understand the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem:

```
(SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(mm, myfield, myfield),103), 103) 
<= CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, myfield, 103), 103) 
                FROM
                  mytable A 
                WHERE
                  mycondition = '607')
```

If you remove the `SELECT` it removes the error line under the `<=`. Without further detail of the tables/columns, I can't go too deep into an answer. But you might try something similar to this (hypothetical example):

```
(CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(mm, mytable.myfield, othertable.myfield),103), 103) 
<= CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, mytable.myfield, 103), 103) 
                )
                and
                  mycondition = '607'
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `SELECT` a boolean value:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(mm, myfield, myfield),103), 103)
    <= 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, myfield, 103), 103) 
    -- INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR '<'
```

replace this expression with a `CASE` evaluating to 1 or 0:

```
(SELECT CASE WHEN
    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(mm, myfield, myfield),103), 103)
    <= 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, myfield, 103), 103) 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ...
) = 1
```